# How to handle timer services in a large scale javaee project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I'm building a system that includes bidding on items also. So each item that is put on auction has a timeout. My question is, since the system will be accessed by many users and there are many items on auction, will the use of ejb timer service have a great impact on the performance of the system? If so what are the best ways to handle the situation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently studying this [EJB3 In Action](http://www.manning.com/panda2/) book and there is a useful excerpt from this book on Timers. In summary if you need more complex timer configuration, you better off look into more robust timer services like it said below. But, if you need simple day to day routines, EJB3 timers are sufficient. Performance will not be a problem as the Timer service is provided by the Container.

> In the Java EE world, you have a few options for scheduling tasks and
>   activities. Most Java EE application servers come with a scheduling
>   utility that is sufficiently useful. There are also a number of
>   feature-rich, full-scale scheduling packages available for enterprise
>   applications. Flux is an excellent commercial scheduling package,
>   while Quartz is a good-quality open source implementation. EJB timer
>   services are the standard Java EE answer to scheduling. As you’ll soon
>   learn, while it does not try to compete with full-scale scheduling
>   products, the EJB 3 timer service is probably sufficient for most
>   day-to-day application development requirements. Because it is so
>   lightweight, the service is also extremely easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

> will the use of ejb timer service have a great impact on the performance of the system?

In term of processing it's very cheap for an app server, control the lifecyle of en ejb timer, basicly this is to evaluate if the defined time condition has expired and then to call the timeout() callback method.

The problems begins when it execute the code that you write in order to resolve your business requirement. Here is where performance issues can appear.

I don't know how you are planning to use the timer service, but what I'm imagining is an ejb timer that every 1 second calls a service offered for your service/business layer that knows how to identify the bids that have expired and do something with them.

How you design this service will impact in the performance not the ejb timer itself.